# In Transit API how to get Bus number

Tags: here-api

In transit rest API how can I find bus number. Response already included direction name  but bus number is missing. Please help me to get bus number?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a particular station name by requesting below request provided that you have to pass stationId which you can get from [here](https://transit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_name.json%20?app_id=%7BYOUR_APP_ID%7D%20&app_code=%7BYOUR_APP_CODE%7D%20&center=40.7510,-73.9916%20&name=New%20York)

```
https://transit.api.here.com/v3/board.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&lang=en
&stnId=703280098
&time=2019-06-24T07%3A30%3A00
```

also please see the [documentation](http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/public_transit_hlp/3.3.0/Public%20Transit%20API%20v3.3.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf) for more reference.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need Bus number.

Answer (score 0):

Just a Hunch Try adding all the bus numbers to a list and redirecting them according to the station no or time of arrival!